# cython tuple indexing on a n-dimensional array

Tags: python, indexing, cython

I am trying to port some **working** existing  numpy/python code to cython

One problem I hit is that I cannot use tuple indexing for a multidimensional array in cython, whereas in python/numpy it does work.

here is a simple mwe:

**cython_indexing.pyx**

```
# cython: boundscheck=False
# cython: wraparound=False
def loop(int axis, double[:, :, :] a, double[:, :, :] b):
    cdef:
        int k, j, i
        tuple q, qp1

    for k in range(a.shape[0]):
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            for i in range(a.shape[2]):
                q = (k, j, i)
                if axis == 0:
                    qp1 = (k + 1, j, i)
                elif axis == 1:
                    qp1 = (k, j + 1, i)
                elif axis == 2:
                    qp1 = (k, j, i + 1)

                # ...
                # some other operations
                # with heavy reuse of q, qp1
                # ...

                a[q] = a[q] - (b[qp1] - b[q])
```

**test_indexing.py**

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import numpy as np
from cython_indexing import loop

a = np.arange(27).astype('float').reshape(3, 3, 3)
b = a**2

for axis in (0, 1, 2):
    loop(axis, a, b)
```

this example is throwing an error at compilation time on `b[qp1] - b[q]`:

```
Invalid operand types for '-' (double[:, :]; double[:, :])
```

is there any simple solution **NOT** involving to change the code architecture ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that Cython doesn't know how big the tuple is at compile time, so it can't sensibly do the array indexing at compile time - it doesn't know how many dimensions the array it has to return has. (It looks like it just gets confused, but even if it did work then it would have to take a "generic Python `__getitem__` code-path, and so you'd get no speed up).

There's two (not too difficult) changes you could make. The first is to do what I think you want to avoid when you say

> any simple solution **NOT** involving to change the code architecture

is to use 3 ints instead of a tuple:

```
cdef:
   int q0, q1, q2, qp1_0, qp1_1, qp1_2

# ....
a[q0,q1,q2] = a[q0,q1,q2] - (b[qp1_0,qp1_1,qp1_2] - b[q0,q1,q2])
```

The second would be not to uses Cython's "typed-memoryview" interface, and to let `a` and `b` be untyped:

```
def loop(int axis, a, b):
```

This would let the indexing work with tuples (as in pure Python) but would not be significantly faster than pure Python.

Unfortunately this is the trade-off: if you want faster speed then you have to avoid using Python objects such as tuples.

Comment: Thanks DavidW. Is also tried to index the memoryview with a compiled time size fixed integer array i.e. cdef int q[3], but it does not work either. Yep I thought of using new integers,  but this is a tradeoff for readability ... As you might think, the 2nd option is not a realistic option.